# The function of this "ing" form; What does it mean?

Tags: grammar

Nine in 10 of the 1,288 girls and young women interviewed for the Girlguiding study said women are judged for their looks more than their ability, **causing** one in five girls as young as seven to go on a diet.

Does this "causing" mean, "which causes ...."

I mean like this.

This "which" means the fact that "women are judged for their looks more than their ability."

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You are right. "Being judged ..." causes "one in five girls (as young as seven) to go on a diet".

Answer (score 1):

Almost! You've got the basic idea down, but it actually means *which caused*, not *which causes*. The study already happened, and 1 in 5 of those 1,288 girls in the study reported that they *already went on a diet* because of this societal pressure. It's implied that, if the study is an accurate sample of the population, 1 in 5 of all girls would, on into the future, also be caused to go on a diet. But the direct information is only that *the girls in the study were caused to do so*, not that *the pressure causes all girls to do so*.

Comment: +1 But I'm afraid that your understanding of what inferences may be drawn from the data is considerably more sophisticated than the author's.